# Sweet potatoes: Can I plant a whole tuber instead of starting slips? Are slips a better option?

Tags: sweet-potato

I'm in zone 4 (Minneapolis MN, USA) and managed to grow some sweet potatoes last year with the 3 month window (I bought slips), but this year I have the saved tubers from last year. Should I grow slips or could I simply plant the tubers? I can't risk much due to our narrow window.

Comment: Can't you start some slips from your tubers?

Comment: @Graham Chiu For sure, but was wondering about pros and cons of just putting a tuber in the ground as opposed to starting slips. I'd read folks have done it that way, but don't want to screw things up if that's a bad idea.

Comment: One tuber will give you many more slips and therefore sweet potatoes than the tuber planted in one area.

Comment: Follow-up: 2 months before planting, I put the tubers in a little bit of soil indoors and it established a LOT of roots and slips. I didn't break any slips off, but instead I planted the whole tuber, So far it's grown much faster than last year. My guess is that using the soil before planting outdoors was what helped, but we'll see how it turns out!